# Aviation signals probability

Tags: probability, independence

I'm trying to solve this exercise but i don't know where to start. The exercise is:

I have two types of signals with codes $111$ or $000$ with probabilities of $0.65$ and $0.35$ respectively. These signals are distorted by noise, which provocates that a $1$ (sent) can be receipt as $0$ with a probability of $0.2$ and the converse with $0.8$. Suppose that the symbols suffers these noises independently.

Which is the probability of get in the output we receive the signals $111$, $000$ and $010$ ?

Comment: What is the probability that we receive 111? Is this your first question?
What is the probability that we receive 000? Is this your second question?
What is the probability that we receive 010? Is this your third question?

Answer (score 1):

$111$ sent and received correctly $(0.65\cdot0.80^3)$

$000$ sent and received as $111$ $(0.35\cdot0.20^3)$

P(111) received $(0.65\cdot0.80^3) + (0.35\cdot0.20^3)$

$111$ sent and received as 010 $=(0.65\cdot0.80\cdot 0.2^2)$

$000$ sent and received as 010 $=(0.35\cdot0.80^2\cdot 0.2)$

etc.

Comment: $\checkmark$ In short, use the Law of Total Probability : $$\def\P{\mathop{\mathsf P}}\begin{align}\P(R{=}111) ~&=~ \P(S{=}000)\P(R{=}111\mid S{=}000)+\P(S{=}111)\P(R{=}111\mid S{=}111)\\[1ex] &=~ 0.65\cdot 0.80^3+0.35\cdot 0.20^3 \end{align}$$